# How to retrofit

Tags: node.js, retrofit

I'm new to NodeJS and Retrofit and I can't seem to get POST/PUT/DELTE to work.

For example, my back-end end point:

```js
routes.post('/createGame', async (req, res) => {
  const game = await models.game.model.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    rules: req.body.rules,
    requirements: req.body.requirements,
    type: req.body.type
  });
  res.send(game);
});
```

as for my retrofit request, I've tried with FormUrlEncoded:

```
    @POST("createGame")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun createGame(
        @Field("name") name: String,
        @Field("description") description: String,
        @Field("rules") rules: String,
        @Field("requirements") requirements: String,
        @Field("type") type: GameType
    ): Deferred<Game>
```

I've done this without using any tags and I've tried with `@Body` for every parameter but that's not how body works (I don't want to pass it as an object)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically @Field annotation has an option field for encoding:

encoded: can be either true or false; default is false
The encoded option defines whether your provided key-value-pair is already url encoded. To specify the encoded option value, you need to pass it within the @Field annotation. The example below illustrates a code examples and sets the encoded option to true.

```
@Field(value = "title", encoded = true) String title
```

More information on working with Retrofit could be found [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html).

Comment: but will these parameters then come inside the body of the request that comes into my nodejs express backend?

Comment: I'd suggest to make an interface and put the parameters inside it, and then call it from you main class.